# Develop Ubuntu Device Drivers

Tags: drivers

I am trying to write a simple device driver according to the book "Linux Device Drivers" but can't set up the correct include path. I am using a simple make script. The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-29-generic on an old intel (Pentium D (EMT/64 bit) based PC. I've tried:

`I/usr/src/include`
    -> Error can't find module.h (there should be links but wasn't there)

`I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic/include and copied .config from /boot/...`
  -> works for a while but can't find asm includes

In the above include directory I found a directory named asm-generic so I made a link `asm -> asm-generic`. Works again a little bit further until a file `asm/Thread_info.h` is searched.
Found many of it in hardware dependent directory structure. Before I mess up the whole system with setting up more links what is the correct way to set up the include path?

Answer (score 0):

For kernel drivers you should be including the path `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include`. Do not use `/usr/src/include` - that is the path for user space headers.

Note that the "Linux Device Drivers" book is outdated now (~10 years old) and many of the examples will fail to compile. There is a github repository that has the original source patched to compile with more recent kernels at https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3

Comment: Thank's a lot. That was the hint i needed. I've startet reading the outdated version 2 of this book. The makefile from Version 3 works fine so far. If i run into trouble again, i will take a look at the patched files. Thanks again